# Como iniciar um objeto em TypeScript sem declarar todas as propriedades de uma vez?

Tags: javascript, typescript, tipagem

Levando em consideração a seguinte `interface`:

```
interface Usuario {
    nome: string;
    senha: string;
    email: string;
}
```

É possível declarar um objeto "aos poucos", sem criar um novo `type` ou `interface` com todas propriedades sendo opcionais (`?`)? Se sim, como? Exemplo:

```
function criarUsuario(nome: string, senha: string, email: string): Usuario {
    const usuario: Usuario = {}; // Aqui ocorre um erro porque o objeto ainda está vazio
    // ...
    usuario.nome = nome;
    usuario.senha = senha;
    usuario.email = email;
    return usuario;
}
```

<sup>O exemplo está simplificado, sei que nessa situação não faz sentido definir propriedade por propriedade.</sup>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o tipo embutido [`Partial<T>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialt), que torna todas as propriedades do tipo `T` opcionais:

```js
interface Usuario {
    nome: string;
    senha: string;
    email: string;
}

function criarUsuario(nome: string, senha: string, email: string): Usuario {
    const usuario: Partial<Usuario> = {};

    usuario.nome = nome;
    usuario.senha = senha;

    // Note que, embora `usuario.email` não tenha sido fornecido,
    // nenhum aviso ou erro é emitido pelo compilador.
    return usuario as Usuario;
}
```

<sup>[Veja no TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=13&pc=2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGcCucrAPbIDeAUMmciHgLYQBcy6YuIA5gNynnoQgAWc9Rs3acyEKnGAAbQU1AiAvsWIxMIBGHwhkCXDgzZceABSUas4QBoGPfhfnXxkmQzmsAlPQM58RUTrwQRmRMLB88egAFHE04KQAebyMAPmQAXiIFDn9Qw3wAOjMUDKKOchCwo3zuPjh0m1rs8oB6ZuQAOTxIZABHTAhHKgAjPCg6gANc8PynaXGKAGOCSFqGYAATAhhRkAgEDbxLf1aKW0wqZDgAN2B0AjxMZGgoAgBLp6pgTU3kAAcIKQEBDUX7SOCbKD5fxQCBgTBQbRTIyXdBoSr4DgKIA).</sup>

O problema é que com isso você precisará de fazer uma asserção no retorno para dizer ao compilador que o objeto que você está retornando é realmente um usuário "completo". Caso contrário, o TypeScript reclamará dizendo que `Partial<Usuario>` não é atribuível à `Usuario`.

Note que no exemplo acima eu omiti o `email` e mesmo assim o compilador não emite erros. Portanto, você está abrindo mão da "segurança" em um certo nível. Eu pessoalmente não considero isso bom e tento sempre evitar.

Uma outra forma de resolver isso é simplesmente utilizar a asserção de tipo logo na declaração (atribuição ao objeto vazio). No entanto, isso também não resolve o problema da falta de segurança de tipos, conforme você pode verificar no código abaixo:

```
interface Usuario {
    nome: string;
    senha: string;
    email: string;
}

function criarUsuario(nome: string, senha: string, email: string): Usuario {
    const usuario = {} as Usuario;
    usuario.nome = nome;
    usuario.senha = senha;
    // Note que também nenhum erro foi emitido.
    return usuario;
}
```

<sup>[Veja no TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=11&ssc=48&pln=11&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGcCucrAPbIDeAUMmciHgLYQBcy6YuIA5gNynnoQgAWc9Rs3acyEKnGAAbQU1AiAvsWIxMIBGHwhkCXDgzZceABSUas4QBoGPfhfnXxkmQzmsAlPQM58RUTrwQRmRMLB8CAF4iBWQ4dDQwow5yEMT8ADozFCis5PJQwwzuPjhkKOL%20PLIAemrkADk8SGQAR0wUMDgqACMAS6oKW0wB6CgCGDxgZHFgTQATPHT-KAgwTChtAvCOBSA).</sup>

#### O que fazer então?

No seu exemplo, você poderia simplesmente adicionar todas as propriedades durante a inicialização literal do objeto. Para garantir a "segurança" que tanto falei, esta é a melhor forma.

```
interface Usuario {
    nome: string;
    senha: string;
    email: string;
}

function criarUsuario(nome: string, senha: string, email: string): Usuario {
    const usuario: Usuario = {
        nome,
        senha,
        email
    };

    return usuario;
}
```

<sup>[Veja no TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=15&pc=2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGcCucrAPbIDeAUMmciHgLYQBcy6YuIA5gNynnoQgAWc9Rs3acyEKnGAAbQU1AiAvsWIxMIBGHwhkCXDgzZceABSUas4QBoGPfhfnXxkmQzmsAlPQM58RUTrwQRmRMLB88LzCjZABeP3IEimoIS38E7j44VMTyJ2l-BQ5-KAgwTChtUMN8DgUgA).</sup>

Na grande maioria das vezes é possível utilizar essa abordagem.