# Inicializar objeto com tipo definido sem especificar cada valor

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, tipagem

Gostaria de inicializar um objeto sem definir cada valor no TypeScript

Vamos simular uma situação simples em que temos o Objeto Carro:

```
export interface Carro {
      QuantidadePortas: number,
      Marca: string,
      Modelo: number,
      AnoFabricacao: number
    }
```

Para **inicializar** o objeto antes de preenche-lo com as devidas informações sou obrigado a definir cada valor:

```
carroSelecionado: Carro = {QuantidadePortas: 0, Marca: '', Modelo: 0, AnoFabricacao: 0000};
```

Porém quando tenho objetos grandes com mais de 20/30 valores dificulta demais.

**Aí vem a pergunta, tem alguma maneira de fazer essa inicialização de maneira mais fácil?**

Comment: Não entendi pq está usando `interface` ao invés de uma `classe`, sendo que classes podem ser **instanciadas** e interfaces não, o que seria melhor nesse contexto por exemplo. Se trocar interface por classe, no lugar onde precisa utilizar a classe **`Carro`** seria apenas fazer `carro: Carro = new Carro();`

Comment: Mas interfaces são utilizadas para definir tipos e classes são utilizadas para outras coisas, não?

Comment: Que outras coisas classes definem?

Comment: Eu não entendi a pergunta, não sei se tem a ver com isso: [Como iniciar um objeto em TypeScript sem declarar todas as propriedades de uma vez?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/458404/100416)

Comment: Dentro da Pergunta que o Rafael Tavares referenciou tem exatamente o que você está querendo: carroSelecionado = {} as Carro; Pergunta referenciada pelo Rafael Tavares: [Como iniciar um objeto em TypeScript sem declarar todas as propriedades de uma vez?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/458404/100416)

Comment: Respondeu sim, obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Em TypeScript temos os valores declarados obrigatórios e não obrigatórios, por exemplo:

```
QuantidadePortas: number
```

É um atributo obrigatório.
Para torná-lo opcional, deve colocar `?` antes do :, dessa forma:

```
QuantidadePortas?: number
```

Comment: Removi o "oi, tudo bem?", entenda o motivo lendo aqui: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/846/112052

Answer (score -1):

Agradecer pelo comentário do Rafael Tavares que tem a [resposta aqui no StackOverflow](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/458404/como-iniciar-um-objeto-em-typescript-sem-declarar-todas-as-propriedades-de-uma-v) e resolveu meu problema.

Adotei esse padrão para inicializar objetos

```
carroSelecionado = {} as Carro;
```

Comment: Ao fazer isso você está burlando as checagens do TypeScript. Isso pode te trazer problemas, já que o TypeScript dirá que o objeto já foi declarado com todas propriedades devidas

Comment: Nesse caso o TypeScript não irá checar os tipo quando associar uma resposta valida ao objeto?

Comment: Se você fizer `let carroSelecionado = {} as Carro;` e tentar `carroSelecionado.QuantidadePortas`, receberá `undefined` sem o TypeScript reclamar (o que é errado). Se posteriormente associar um objeto válido ao `carroSelecionado`, conseguirá acessar as propriedades normalmente.

Comment: Então o certo seria mesmo definir um valor inicial para cada propiedade?

Comment: A resposta que você mencionou tem as opções que você pode utilizar. Ou use `Partial<Carro>` ou definia as propriedades na declaração.